# Using VisualForce pages/controllers

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

How can visualforce pages and their respective controllers be hosted on SFDC but have my own domain name and URL extension being used when directing users to them?

I am building pages in VisualForce with Apex controller extensions in the background and would like to know how to direct my users to them whilst still prepended the filename with my own URL and not na9.salesforce......

Would these pages have to be hosted on Sites.com Or can I host them as pages in my developer.force.com account? I think the first because if they were to be hosted within SFDC then a login would be required to view the pages?

I am so confused that things are not going well. I know that SFDC want everything to be integrated but i think that users should just be happy with a single solution that does not have modules thrown all over the place where you need bespoke training to use effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce.com's Sites is the technology that you are going to need to use if you want to provide your own domain (URL). Essentially, with that technology you can setup a guest account for anonymous user access. So everything still runs under the context of a user it would just be this generic guest account.

This article explains the details of mapping your Domain to the Salesforce.com Site domain.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Sites_Best_Practices